# Contact Form 7 Captcha not Working on XAMPP server

Tags: wordpress, forms, xampp, captcha, contact-form

I am developing my WordPress website locally using **XAMPP** server, but Contact Form 7 Captcha functionality does not work. That is, clicking on the Submit button, a spinning arrow appears and the form does not do any thing.

I tried this with a different theme and the trouble does persist. I guess this related to XAMPP. Is there any solution?

Comment: you need to restart the XAMPP...Also post your relevant code.

Comment: @krupalshah Restarting XAMPP was not helpful. What code do you mean? the Form code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want contact form 7 to send email when installed on XAMPP, it will not do because email SMTP is not configured on localhost. it needs to be configured and due to this contact form does nothing and waits for response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have no trouble with sending email using Contact Form 7 locally. Actually, the relevant plugin Really Simple Captcha is my problem. It creates a captcha image, but clicking on the Submit button bears no result other than appearing a spinning arrow and no email is sent and no message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 Image Captcha is replacable for visual captcha
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-image-captcha/installation/